# can OGNL evaluate an expression which mixes normal string with property name?

Tags: java, expression, ognl

I want to use OGNL to evaluate an expression, this expression contains normal string and property name.

unit test code:

```
@Test
public void evaluate_ognl() throws OgnlException
{
     String expression = "hello:{#this.name}";
     Object expr = Ognl.parseExpression(expression);
     OgnlContext ctx = new OgnlContext();
     Student s = new Student();
     s.setAge(12);
     s.setName("lig");
     Object value = Ognl.getValue(expr, ctx, s);
     System.out.println(value);
}
```

`Student` class has two properties: age & name, so here I want to print:`hello:lig`, but it didn't, it throws an exception meaning `hello:{#this.name}` is not a legal expression, I don't know how to fix it, or does OGNL support this mixed style expression?

Comment: __PS__: I found a solution: expression should be this: 'hello'.concat(#this.name)